# Focusout is not working on mobile devices when pressing keypads done button, but working on document click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

```js
$('#something').on("focusout", function(ev) {
   if(ev.type == "focusout"){alert('Working');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='something'>
```

This code works perfectly with large screen devices, But when I try using it on mobile, After typing something when I press done (*mobile keypad's button*) nothing happens, whenever I click on the document (*mobile browser's screen*) after that, it works fine, Same if I just wrote something but instead of pressing done I am pressing on the document it is working fine.

I'm using `Opera Mobile Emulator`, Is this problem only for `Opera Browser`?

Comment: Have you tried using `blur` instead of `focusout`?

Comment: Can you add done `button` also please?

Comment: @Ionut  Yes, Same problem.

Comment: @RohitSharma For the code to work with it instead of of `focusout`?

Comment: @CaliburVictorious Just add one more button in the same code that you are talking about.

Comment: @RohitSharma As a solution or for a purpose to solve the problem? Because i don't want to use buttons.

Comment: talking about that you wrote ***and press (Done) nothing happens***.

Comment: @RohitSharma Its is the Mobile Emulator keypad, When you type and then press done.

Comment: Why don't you write a function and call it on button click? Won't it achieve your goal?

Comment: @Ananya Mobile devices keypads are treated differently, For Big-Screen Devices keyboards for example, `which == 13` is for `Enter`, But for Mobile Devices, I checked their `Keycodes` for `Done` button, But didn't work either.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YQxXN/1/ Try this once. if it helps

Comment: @Ananya example uses normal html button, i aim for the `Mobile Devices Keypad`, I'm trying to achieve for both Android and iOS for now.

Comment: `var blurOccurred;

$('#something')
.on("blur", function(evt) {
  blurOccurred = window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Done button clicked');
  }, 10);
})
.on("focus", function(evt) {
  window.clearTimeout(blurOccurred);
});`

Try this once

Comment: @Ananya As i mentioned in the third comment, It has the same problem, It doesn't identify `blur` or `focusout` unless i clicked on the `document` again.

Comment: `<button id="myButton" onclick="handler();">Click me</button>
..you can also handle this event using the event handlers in JavaScript. 

Hide   Copy Code
// myButton is the ID of the button, upon click
myButton.addEventListener("click", 
   // run this function
   function () {
       // show an alert dialog box
       alert("Button was clicked.");
   }
);` Did you try this way?

Comment: @Ananya in my 6th comment, I'm trying not to use `Buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function submitForm(e) {
    alert('form submitted');
    
    e.preventDefault();
}

(function() {
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
}());
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="submit" value="Done">
</form>
```

I have checked this above code in android and form is getting submitted on  Enter button click. Kindly give it a try.